# Some data is being lost upon calculation

Tags: c#, winforms

UPDATE: Whenever values are entered in classes 2 onwards the only result that is shown is that of the last entered inputs. So for example: if data is entered in class1 row and class2 row only calculations for class2 row is displayed. Could someone tell me why this is happening please?

[image: gpa Calculator]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Grade_Point_Average_Calculator
{
    public partial class GPA_Calculator : Form
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1;

        public GPA_Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GPA_Calculator_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        //  Closes application after exitToolStripMenuItem_Click
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


        // Displays information about the application version number and creator
        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Version 1.0., "About");
        }

        private void calculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int maskbox1, maskbox2, maskbox3, maskbox4, maskbox5, maskbox6;

        CalculatorLogics oCalculatorLogics1 = new CalculatorLogics(this);
        oCalculatorLogics1.SelectedGrade = double.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        if (!int.TryParse(maskedTextBox1.Text, out maskbox1))
        {
            maskbox1 = 0; // Assign zero is parse fails
        }
        else 
        {
            oCalculatorLogics1.CourseCredit = int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
        }
        oCalculatorLogics1.performGpaCalculations();
        answerLabel.Text = oCalculatorLogics1.CalcGrade.ToString();


        CalculatorLogics oCalculatorLogics2 = new CalculatorLogics(this);
        oCalculatorLogics2.SelectedGrade =            double.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        if (!int.TryParse(maskedTextBox2.Text, out maskbox1))
        {
            maskbox2 = 0; // Assign zero is parse fails
        }
        else
        {
            oCalculatorLogics2.CourseCredit = int.Parse(maskedTextBox2.Text);
        }
        oCalculatorLogics2.performGpaCalculations();
        answerLabel.Text = oCalculatorLogics2.CalcGrade.ToString();

        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Grade_Point_Average_Calculator
{
    class CalculatorLogics
    {

        private double grade;
        private double gradeValue;
        private double calculateGrades;
        private int credits;
        private GPA_Calculator _GPA_Calculator;

        // Pass form to CalculatorLogics constructor
        public CalculatorLogics(GPA_Calculator theGPA_Calculator)
        {
            _GPA_Calculator = theGPA_Calculator;
        }

        public double SelectedGrade 
        {
            get { return grade; }
            set { grade = value; }
        }

        public int CourseCredit 
        {
            get { return credits; }
            set { credits = value; }
        }

        public double CalcGrade 
        {
            get 
            {
            return calculateGrades; 
            }
        }

        public void performGpaCalculations() 
        {
            gradeVal = grade * credits;
            totalCredits += credits; // Add the amount of credits
            totalGradeValue += gradeVal;

            calculateGrades = totalGradeValue/totalCredits; // Calculates gpa
            return calculateGrades;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: What is the problem? Where is the other window form that you are trying to interact with?

Comment: You would need to invoke the performGpaCalculations method before the CalcGrade property would be set to anything correct?

Comment: I am a c++ programmer but I am guessing the problem is inside the class (switch thing). I don't think it understands which form to use, since it creates new object. I would suggest making a class function and passing combobox value as an argument to that function and function will do the job and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

As the code stands, your issue is that you are not calling the `performGpaCalculations()` method in your `CalculatorLogics` class and this is causing the `calculateGrades` value returned from the `CalcGrade` property to be the default value of a `double` (0.0).

You need to call the `performGpaCalculations()` method in your code, like this:

```
private void calculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculatorLogics oCalculatorLogics = new CalculatorLogics();
    oCalculatorLogics.performGpaCalculations();
    answerLabel.Text = oCalculatorLogics.CalcGrade.ToString();
}
```

This will allow the `CalcGrade` class to determine the value of `calculateGrades`.

UPDATE:

But your real problem is that you are instantiating a new instance of the form class `GPA_Calculator`, which blows away the values the user selected.

Instead you need to pass an instance of the `GPA_Calculator` form class to the constructor of your `CalculatorLogics` class, like this:

```
public CalculatorLogics(GPA_Calculator theGPA_Calculator)
{

}
```

Now that your form is being passed to the constructor, you need somewhere to store it so the `CalculatorLogics` class can use it, here is a rewrite of your `CalculatorLogics` class to support this:

```
public class CalculatorLogics
{
    private double grade;
    private double gradeValue;
    private double calculateGrades;
    private int credits;
    private GPA_Calculator _GPA_Calculator;

    public CalculatorLogics(GPA_Calculator theGPA_Calculator)
    {
        _GPA_Calculator = theGPA_Calculator;
    }

    public double SelectedGrade 
    {
        get { return grade; }
        set { grade = value; }
    }

    public int CourseCredit 
    {
        get { return credits; }
        set { credits = value; }
    }

    public double CalcGrade 
    {
        get 
        {
        return calculateGrades; 
        }
    }

    public void performGpaCalculations() 
    {
        const double grade_A = 4.00;
        const double grade_A_minus = 3.67;
        const double grade_B_plus = 3.33;
        const double grade_B = 3.00;
        const double grade_B_minus = 2.67;
        const double grade_C_plus = 2.33;
        const double grade_C = 2.00;
        const double grade_C_minus = 1.67;
        const double grade_D = 1.33;
        const double grade_F = 0.00;

        switch (_GPA_Calculator.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) 
        {
            case "A":
                gradeValue = grade_A;
                break;
            case "A-":
                gradeValue = grade_A_minus;
                break;
            case "B+":
                gradeValue = grade_B_plus;
                break;
            case "B":
                gradeValue = grade_B;
                break;
            case "B-":
                gradeValue = grade_B_minus;
                break;
            case "C+":
                gradeValue = grade_C_plus;
                break;
            case "C":
                gradeValue = grade_C;
                break;
            case "C-":
                gradeValue = grade_C_minus;
                break;
            case "D":
                gradeValue = grade_D;
                break;
           case "F":
                gradeValue = grade_F;
                break;
        }
        calculateGrades = gradeValue * credits;
    }
}
```

Finally, when you instantiate your `CalculatorLogics` class you will need to pass a reference to the form you are in, like this:

```
CalculatorLogics oCalculatorLogics = new CalculatorLogics(this);
```

Note: `this` is a pointer to the class itself, in this case the `GPA_Calculator` form.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the selected values of the comboBoxes, it does not help to just create a new instance of the form class.

Instead, you may pass the current form to the method like:

```
public void performGpaCalculations(GPA_Calculator form)
```

or better just pass a list of the selected items:

```
public void performGpaCalculations(int[] selectedValues)
```

int[] because i would suggest you to not use selectedItem of the comboBox but selectedIndex and create a static grade array

```
double[] grades = {4.00, 3.67, // ...
```

so you don't need that switch.

UPDATE:
OK, the answer above was updated with what I wrote, so my answer won't be helpful anymore...